# Math Mod Containing Numbers

Tags: math

i would like to write a simple line of code, without resorting to if statements, that would evaluate whether a number is within a certain range.  i can evaluate from 0 - Max by using the modulus.

```
30 % 90 = 30  //great
```

however, if the test number is greater than the maximum, using modulus will simply start it at 0 for the remaining, where as i would like to limit it to the maximum if it's past the maximum

```
94 % 90 = 4  //i would like answer to be 90
```

it becomes even more complicated, to me anyway, if i introduce a minimum for the range.  for example:

```
minimum = 10
maximum = 90
```

therefore, any number i evaluate should be either within range, or the minimum value if it's below range and the maximum value if it's above range

```
-76 should be 10
2 should be 10
30 should be 30
89 should be 89
98 should be 90
23553 should be 90
```

is it possible to evaluate this with one line of code without using if statements?

Comment: It helps if you specify the language you're working with.

Comment: sorry.  i didn't state my language because i assumed most languages have the same operators or Math methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the simplest way is to use whatever `max` and `min` are available in your language like this:

```
max(10, min(number, 90))
```

In some languages, e.g. Java, JavaScript, and C# (and probably others) `max` and `min` are static methods of the `Math` class.

I've used a `clip` function to make it easier (this is in JavaScript):

```
function clip(min, number, max) {
    return Math.max(min, Math.min(number, max));
}
```

Comment: excellent!  this is much easier than trying to use the modulus operator.  exactly what i'm looking for.  thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

simple, but still branches even though `if` is not used:

```
r = ( x < minimum ) ? minimum : ( x > maximum ) ? maximum : x;
```

from [bit twiddling hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerMinOrMax), assuming (2<3) == 1:

```
r = y ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y)); // min(x, y)
r = x ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y)); // max(x, y)
```

putting it together, assuming min < max:

```
r = min^(((max^((x^max)&-(max<x)))^min)&-(x<min));
```

how it works when `x<y`:

```
r = y ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y));
r = y ^ ((x ^ y) & -(1)); // x<y == 1
r = y ^ ((x ^ y) & ~0); // -1 == ~0
r = y ^  (x ^ y); // (x^y) & ~0 == (x^y)
r = y ^   x ^ y; // y^y == 0
r = x;
```

otherwise:

```
r = y ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y));
r = y ^ ((x ^ y) & -(0)); // x<y == 0
r = y ^ ((x ^ y) & 0); // -0 == 0
r = y; // (x^y) & 0 == 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using C/C++:

```
value = min*(number < min) +
        max*(number > max) +
        (number <= max && number >= min)*number%max;
```

The following is a brief explanation. Note that the code depends on 2 important issues to work correctly. First, in C/C++ a boolean expression can be converted to an integer. Second, the reminder of a negative number is the number it self. So, it is not the mathematical definition of the remainder. I am not sure if this is defined by the C/C++ standards or it is left to the implementation. Basically:

```
if number < min then:
    value = min*1 +
            max*0 +
            0*number%max;
else if number  > max
    value = min*0 +
            max*1 +
            0*number%max;
else
    value = min*1 +
            max*1 +
            1*number%max;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a language that has a ternary operator (such as C or Java), you could do it like this:

```
t < lo ? lo : (t > hi ? hi : t)
```

where t is the test variable, and lo and hi are the limits.  That satisfies your constraints, in that it doesn't strictly use if-statements, but the ternary operator is really just syntactic sugar for an if-statement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you could...

(X / 10) < 1 ? 10 : (X / 90 > 1 ? 90 : X)

Number divided by 10 is less than 1? set to 10
Else
If number divided by 90 is greater than 90, set to 90
Else
set to X

Note that it's still hidden ifs. :(

Comment: Also note that you should take those parens' placement with a grain of salt! :)